# 'tail' command not getting only the new lines

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

I'm using the command:

```
tail -f -n 0 file.txt
```

But it keeps repeating itself.

---

1. What I'm doing is the following:
2. Create the file in the first terminal: `touch file.txt`
3. Start the tail in the second terminal: `tail -f -n 0 file.txt`
4. Edit the file in the first terminal: `nano file.txt`
5. Just add `text`, save and close. The second terminal outputs  `text` like it should.
6. Edit the file again in the first terminal: `nano file.txt`
7. Add in the end (2nd line) `more text`, save and close. The second terminal outputs:

> tail: file.txt: file truncated
>      text
>      more text

Edit the file again in the first terminal: `nano file.txt`

Add in the end (3rd line) `even more text`, save and close. The second terminal outputs `even more text` like it should.

Edit the file again in the first terminal: `nano file.txt`

Add in the end (4th line) `and even more text`, save and close. The second terminal outputs:

```
tail: file.txt: file truncated
text
more text
even more text
and even more text
```

---

I need the command to not repeat itself.

The output resulted in:

```
tail -f -n 0 file.txt
text
tail: file.txt: file truncated
text
more text
even more text
tail: file.txt: file truncated
text
more text
even more text
and even more text
```

And I need it to output:

```
tail -f -n 0 file.txt
text
more text
even more text
and even more text
```

Or, if it's not possible to remove the "file truncated" message, something like:

```
tail -f -n 0 file.txt
text
tail: file.txt: file truncated
more text
even more text
tail: file.txt: file truncated
and even more text
```

I also don't know why it gives the file truncated message. I start inserting the new text at the end of the file.

Comment: Does nano insert (append) new text to the existing file? Or does it empty (truncate) the file and then write the new (longer) version?  Which is a new write which would trigger tail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you get the error because you are using a text editor for this. This means that every time you open the file, edit and save it, the original is overwritten with the new contents. Whether you added a single line to the end or 100 lines all over the place is irrelevant, the point is that the file is being opened, edited and saved and that overwrites the contents.

For example, compare your workflow to running this:

```
for((i=0;i<20;i++)); do echo $i >> file.txt; sleep 1; done
```

That will write a number to `file.txt` every second for twenty seconds. If you open another terminal and run `tail -fn 0 file.txt`, you will see the output you expect.

So, to get the desired behavior add the text to the file using `>>` from a terminal instead of manually editing it.

---

#### More details

`nano` seems to be the odd one out here. Most editors when opening a file then saving it will actually delete the original file and save a new one with the same name. You can test this by checking the [inode number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) of the file:

```
$ ls -il file.txt
16647801 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 9 Apr  6 18:19 file.txt
```

Files are simply hardlinks to specific inodes, in this case, `file.txt` points to inode `16647801`. Now, open the file in `gedit`, add a line and check the inode again:

```
$ gedit file.txt
$ ls -il file.txt
16647854 -rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 13 Apr  6 18:23 file.txt
```

As you see, the inode number has changed, in other words, the original file was removed and a new one was created. `nano` does not do that, trying the same thing with `nano` does not change the inode. It does, however, delete the original contents overwriting them with the new contents. That's why `tail` actually shows the output, if you try it and edit the file with `gedit` (or `emacs` or a number of other editors), the extra lines you add won't be shown in the output of `tail` at all.

Comment: Nano was the problem. Thank you.
Using `echo text >> file.txt` instead of nano solves the problem.

Comment: `nano does however, delete the original and overwrite it with a new file, just pointing to the same inode. ` Are you sure about that? That sounds awfully unportable. Doesn't it just truncate the file and append new content?

Comment: @rr- yes, that's why you get the file truncated error. The original contents were removed (the file was deleted) and then the new contents are appended.

Comment: Deleting a file (`remove(...);` and recreating it from scratch) and truncating its contents (`open(..., O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY);` or `fopen(..., "wb");` or `ftruncate(...)`) is not the same, hence my question. Both can lead to different kind of race conditions.

Comment: @rr- ah, OK, I see what you mean. Well, I ran `strace` on nano and it _looks_ like it first opens `O_RDONLY`, then closes and opens again `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND` at this point it seems to do a `write()` call but I can't tell what it's writing. Finally, it closes again and opens with `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` and then writes the text I told it to write. So, you seem to be quite right and the work is happening with a truncate call. I edited accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for investigating it so thoroughly, that clears things up :)

Answer (score 7):

As stated in one of the other answers already, this is happening because your file is being overwritten each time you save the file. The tail command was designed to monitor log files in which new lines are appended to the file.

In this particular situation I would use the following as a workaround:

```
watch -n 1 cat file.txt
```

The watch command executes a command periodically. The update interval, in seconds, is specified with `-n` and can be adjusted to your liking.